# macos crashlytics crashing while sending report

Tags: macos, cocoapods, crashlytics, google-fabric

i have an issue with my (first) macOS app. A beta Tester gets a crash right on start of the app. 
I am a bit puzzled as to why. 
I have included the crashlytics framework (Version 3.9.3 (128)). It seems to me that is crashing while crashlytics is trying to send a report (from an earlier crash?).

has anyone experienced something similar?

```
2017-11-09 10:22:51.369 AquaCalculator[3959:1399290] [Crashlytics] Version 3.9.3 (128)
2017-11-09 10:22:51.464 AquaCalculator[3959:1399398] [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] Packaged report with id '71a39da2c3fc41b9a563b6c2d0a20f8e' for submission
2017-11-09 10:22:52.966 AquaCalculator[3959:1399290] -[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fff94044b40
Illegal instruction: 4
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
Deleting expired sessions...none found.
```

more details from the crash report:

```
[Process completed]

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Illegal instruction: 4
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x4
Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]

Application Specific Information:
Crashing on exception: -[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fff94044b40

Application Specific Backtrace 1:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff39dad14b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff60df2c76 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff39e45d64 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff39d23530 ___forwarding___ + 1456
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff39d22ef8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   Foundation                          0x00007fff3bf3739a getObjectValue + 444
6   Foundation                          0x00007fff3bf37164 -[NSDateFormatter getObjectValue:forString:errorDescription:] + 471
7   Foundation                          0x00007fff3bf36f79 -[NSDateFormatter dateFromString:] + 50
8   AquaCalculator                      0x0000000100d56215 AquaCalculator + 115221
9   CFNetwork                           0x00007fff38caf4ab __75-[__NSURLSessionLocal taskForClass:request:uploadFile:bodyData:completion:]_block_invoke + 19
10  CFNetwork                           0x00007fff38caed05 __49-[__NSCFLocalSessionTask _task_onqueue_didFinish]_block_invoke + 147
11  Foundation                          0x00007fff3beb925b __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 7
12  Foundation                          0x00007fff3beb90bd -[NSBlockOperation main] + 68
13  Foundation                          0x00007fff3beb756a -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 778
14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff619a8d50 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff619bb333 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 317
16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff619a8d50 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff619bb333 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 317
18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff619bb1d6 dispatch_block_perform + 109
19  Foundation                          0x00007fff3beb3578 __NSOQSchedule_f + 342
20  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff619a8d50 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
21  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff619b432d _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1148
22  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff39d658e9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
23  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff39d27b0a __CFRunLoopRun + 2586
24  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff39d26e63 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 483
25  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff3903fe26 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 286
26  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff3903fb96 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 613
27  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff3903f914 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 64
28  AppKit                              0x00007fff37334483 _DPSNextEvent + 2085
29  AppKit                              0x00007fff37ac9ff8 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 3044
30  AppKit                              0x00007fff37329291 -[NSApplication run] + 764
31  AppKit                              0x00007fff372f8436 NSApplicationMain + 804
32  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff619e2115 start + 1

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff3765ec54 -[NSApplication _crashOnException:] + 109
1   com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff3765eb3c -[NSApplication reportException:] + 953
2   com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff377492ac uncaughtErrorProc + 157
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff39e3f113 __handleUncaughtException + 771
4   libobjc.A.dylib               0x00007fff60df4e9d _objc_terminate() + 91
5   com.thallos.de.AquaCalculator 0x0000000100e31d39 0x100d3a000 + 1015097
6   libc++abi.dylib               0x00007fff5fa857c9 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8
7   libc++abi.dylib               0x00007fff5fa85843 std::terminate() + 51
8   libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff619a8d64 _dispatch_client_callout + 28
9   libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff619bb333 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 317
10  libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff619a8d50 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
11  libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff619bb333 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 317
12  libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff619bb1d6 dispatch_block_perform + 109
13  com.apple.Foundation           0x00007fff3beb3578 __NSOQSchedule_f + 342
14  libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff619a8d50 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
15  libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff619b432d _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1148
16  com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff39d658e9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
17  com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff39d27b0a __CFRunLoopRun + 2586
18  com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff39d26e63 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 483
19  com.apple.HIToolbox           0x00007fff3903fe26 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 286
20  com.apple.HIToolbox           0x00007fff3903fb96 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 613
21  com.apple.HIToolbox           0x00007fff3903f914 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 64
22  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff37334483 _DPSNextEvent + 2085
23  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff37ac9ff8 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 3044
24  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff37329291 -[NSApplication run] + 764
25  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff372f8436 NSApplicationMain + 804
26  libdyld.dylib                 0x00007fff619e2115 start + 1

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff61b32572 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff61c6d06a _pthread_wqthread + 1035
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff61c6cc4d start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: io.answers.EventQueue (QOS: BACKGROUND)
0   com.apple.Foundation           0x00007fff3bef4016 -[NSFilesystemItemRemoveOperation delegate] + 0
1   com.apple.Foundation           0x00007fff3bef3f7b __NSRemoveFileConfirmCallback + 40
2   libremovefile.dylib           0x00007fff61a17861 __removefile_tree_walker + 181
3   libremovefile.dylib           0x00007fff61a17bd7 removefile + 151
4   com.apple.Foundation           0x00007fff3bef3e94 -[NSFilesystemItemRemoveOperation main] + 171
5   com.apple.Foundation           0x00007fff3beb756a -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 778
6   com.apple.Foundation           0x00007fff3bef3d23 -[NSFileManager removeItemAtPath:error:] + 84
7   com.thallos.de.AquaCalculator 0x0000000100e4e49b 0x100d3a000 + 1131675
8   com.thallos.de.AquaCalculator 0x0000000100e48f87 0x100d3a000 + 1109895
9   com.thallos.de.AquaCalculator 0x0000000100e48f09 0x100d3a000 + 1109769
10  com.thallos.de.AquaCalculator 0x0000000100e4e789 0x100d3a000 + 1132425
11  com.thallos.de.AquaCalculator 0x0000000100e433dc 0x100d3a000 + 1086428
12  com.thallos.de.AquaCalculator 0x0000000100e12aa6 0x100d3a000 + 887462
13  com.thallos.de.AquaCalculator 0x0000000100e1284f 0x100d3a000 + 886863
14  com.thallos.de.AquaCalculator 0x0000000100e12996 0x100d3a000 + 887190
15  com.thallos.de.AquaCalculator 0x0000000100e43261 0x100d3a000 + 1086049
16  com.thallos.de.AquaCalculator 0x0000000100e43127 0x100d3a000 + 1085735
17  com.thallos.de.AquaCalculator 0x0000000100e4e669 0x100d3a000 + 1132137
18  com.thallos.de.AquaCalculator 0x0000000100e4924f 0x100d3a000 + 1110607
19  com.apple.CFNetwork           0x00007fff38e68a9f __51-[NSURLSession delegate_task:didCompleteWithError:]_block_invoke.182 + 80
20  com.apple.Foundation           0x00007fff3beb925b __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 7
21  com.apple.Foundation           0x00007fff3beb90bd -[NSBlockOperation main] + 68
22  com.apple.Foundation           0x00007fff3beb756a -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 778
23  libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff619a8d50 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
24  libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff619bb333 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 317
25  libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff619a8d50 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
26  libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff619bb333 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 317
27  libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff619bb1d6 dispatch_block_perform + 109
28  com.apple.Foundation           0x00007fff3beb3578 __NSOQSchedule_f + 342
29  libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff619a8d50 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
30  libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff619bbe76 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 472
31  libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff619b36cb _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 703
32  libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff619aa941 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 515
33  libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff619aa6ed _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 101
34  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff61c6d1ca _pthread_wqthread + 1387
35  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff61c6cc4d start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff61b32572 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff61c6d26f _pthread_wqthread + 1552
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff61c6cc4d start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff61b32572 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff61c6d06a _pthread_wqthread + 1035
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff61c6cc4d start_wqthread + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff61b32572 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff61c6d06a _pthread_wqthread + 1035
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff61c6cc4d start_wqthread + 13

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff61c6cc40 start_wqthread + 0
1   ???                           0x00007ffd8ba0f350 0 + 140726946034512

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff61b32572 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff61c6d06a _pthread_wqthread + 1035
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff61c6cc4d start_wqthread + 13

Thread 8:: com.twitter.crashlytics.mac.MachExceptionServer
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff61b339e2 write + 10
1   com.thallos.de.AquaCalculator 0x0000000100e27b1e 0x100d3a000 + 973598
2   com.thallos.de.AquaCalculator 0x0000000100e1f15c 0x100d3a000 + 938332
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff61c6d6c1 _pthread_body + 340
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff61c6d56d _pthread_start + 377
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff61c6cc5d thread_start + 13

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff61c6cc40 start_wqthread + 0
1   ???                           0x000070000303bbe0 0 + 123145352887264

Thread 10:: com.apple.NSEventThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff61b288f2 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff61b27e0c mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff39d28495 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 341
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff39d277e7 __CFRunLoopRun + 1783
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff39d26e63 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 483
5   com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff37471918 _NSEventThread + 184
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff61c6d6c1 _pthread_body + 340
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff61c6d56d _pthread_start + 377
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff61c6cc5d thread_start + 13

Thread 11:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff61b288f2 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff61b27e0c mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff39d28495 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 341
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff39d277e7 __CFRunLoopRun + 1783
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff39d26e63 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 483
5   com.apple.CFNetwork           0x00007fff38ec744c -[__CoreSchedulingSetRunnable runForever] + 722
6   com.apple.Foundation           0x00007fff3beabe78 __NSThread__start__ + 1197
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff61c6d6c1 _pthread_body + 340
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff61c6d56d _pthread_start + 377
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff61c6cc5d thread_start + 13
```

Answer (score 1):

Mike from Fabric here. I don't believe that this is a crash within Crashlytics. You'll see our threads referenced in most crash reports because our processes are waking up to catch the exception.

The error you're seeing is usually due to memory mismanagement or holding onto an object that's no longer present.

Comment: i think that is correct... just wanted to rule out the possibility.